# Questions about making mirror frame

Tags: wood, furniture, design, framing, planning

I am trying to make a frame for a smart mirror, I have only made the inner frame(in the picture, the sides are 12 inches, and the top and bottom are 28 inches, the monitor is slightly smaller than the mirror) so far. How do I get the measurements for the outer frame, and how do I make the supports to hold the monitor in place?[image: The sides of the frame is 12 inches, and the top and bottom is 28 inches]

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. I think you're going to need to explain or provide a quick pencil sketch of what you mean by 'outer frame'. If it's simply a frame that surrounds the one in the picture you need to complete this one first, then you can mark directly from it — you only get a rough measure from it, for rough cutting.

Comment: Say, uh.... What's a "smart mirror"?